# Can't change text-decoration

Tags: html, css

I need to change text-decoration to none on my preview text, but I can't do it. Perhaps I am using wrong selectors.

```css
.content .main-content.single .post-content{
   text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div class="content clearfix">xxx
    <div class="main-content single">
        <h1 class="post-title"><?php echo $post['title']; ?> </h1>
        <div class="post-content">
       <?php echo html_entity_decode($post['body']); ?>
       xxx
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's in $post['body'] ?

Comment: you need a space between `.main-content` and `.single` in the css stanza

Answer (score 0):

Daniel is right by adding a comma it applies to all and additionally change the `text-decoration: line-through;` to `text-decoration: none;`
**:)**

```
<style>
.content, .main-content.single, .post-content{
   text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
<div class="content clearfix">xxx
    <div class="main-content single">
        <h1 class="post-title"><?php echo $post['title']; ?> </h1>
        <div class="post-content">
       <?php echo html_entity_decode($post['body']); ?>
       xxx
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and add PHP to your question tag